# User delete their own image from folder

Tags: asp.net

I have made an image gallery where users can login and upload images which will be uploaded to the "Data" folder. I have also added a delete button. But the problem is any user can login and delete any image when they click the delete button. How can I make it so that only users who upload their own image are able to delete their own image only and no one else's?

Comment: you could store the images in a subfolder which is the user Id or username

Comment: @Valamas-AUS How can I create a subfolder based on the username? This is the code I have now when it upload the images 'FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Data/" + fileName));'

Comment: try something like `Server.MapPath("~/Data/" + username + +"/" + fileName))` and you may need to create the username subfolder with Directory.CreateDirectory. As for getting the username, you need to figure that out

Comment: @Valamas-AUS Why do you not post this as an answer? I agree with your approach, but why not create an answer of it?